# How is という used in 「男の子の顔は父親より母親ににるという話を聞いた」?

Tags: translation

I came across this Japanese sentence:

> 男の子の顔は父親より母親ににるという話を聞いた。

But am not really sure about its meaning in English.

My translation will be "The man heard that his face resembles his mother more than his father".

But then, I don't quite understand why and how いう話 is being used here. I know that "どういう意味ですか" means "what does it mean" in English. But I can't seem to understand how いう is applied in both sentences. Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 2):

という is a very common construction which has many meanings and causes me endless confusion. But in this case it's straightforward.

という in this context simply means "saying that".

> xxxという話
>   
> story/conversation saying that xxx

> I heard a story saying that boys' faces resemble their mother rather than their father.

Comment: Your English translation is for "男の子の顔**が**父親より母親に似てい**た**".

Comment: @naruto I've fixed the verb tense but I'm afraid the は/が distinction is too subtle for me to understand.

Comment: @user3856370, I'm not a native either, but I believe the sentence expresses a general rule rather than a particular man's face.  I.e. が+似ている would refer to a particular face that resembles ("is resembling") as we speak, while は+似る implies that **any** boy's face **will** resemble...

Comment: @kroki Sounds convincing. I've adjusted accordingley. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain. Just as kroki said.

Answer (score 2):

“という(話、こと)” is one of the most frequently used turn of Japanese phrases you come across everyday, and
its verbatim translation is “the story to the effect of ….” You can simply apply a relative pronoun, “that” to “という〈話、こと〉”

It can be used as in the following examples:

> - 彼、会社を辞めるって**いう**話、本当かい？- Is it true **that** he is leaving the company?
> - 彼がそんなに金に困っていた**という話**、初めて聞いたよ。信じられない - I heard it for the first time **that** he's been in such a financial trouble. It's incredible.
> - 今度の人事異動で、田中が製品開発マネージャーに抜擢される**という**話だ – I heard **that** Tanaka is gonna be promoted to the Product Development Manager in the next personnel changes.
> - **そういう話**は聞きたくない – I don’t want to hear **that kinds of story.**
> - そう**いう**ことだ。これ以上は言うまい - **That’s it**. I won’t say any more.
> - あの会社は潰れる**という**噂が飛んでいる - The word is **that** that company is gonna be bankrupt.
> - 工場を来年３月末までに福島に移転させる**という趣旨**の通知を受け取った - We received a notice **to the effect** **that** the company will relocate the plant to Fukushima by the end of March next year.
> - 要するに、僕の話は聞けない**ということ**だね - In short, you're saying that you don't agree with me, hah?
> - いったい何**と言うことだ**！ - What is this? How could it be?

Comment: 「You can simply apply a **relative pronoun, “that”** to “という〈話、こと〉”」 >> 文法的には、「Is it true **that** +文」「I hear **that** +文」「You're saying **that** + 文」等のthatは、関係代名詞(relative pronoun)ではなく、**名詞節を導く接続詞**です

Comment: Thanks for your usual comment. I wanna tell you that I'm not a grammarian nor English language teacher. I  am just an average or possibly below-average level native Japanese speaker, who happen to be dawn to this site and ammused. How you take "that" in gamatical terms  is all up to you.

Comment: それでは、そこはそのままにして、タイポとフォーマットだけ直させてくださいね。

Comment: @chocolate. Please do it. I'm an awfjul writer and speller, and appreciative of  your corrections.